# IF statement for one variable with multiple values

Tags: freemarker, multiple-value, responsys

Is there a better way to write this IF statement for testing multiple options of a variable?

```
<#if PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME = 'BEST BUY' || PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME = 'Best Buy Purchasing LLC'>
document 1 
<#elseif  PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME = 'AMAZON' || PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME = 'Amazon Fulfillment Services Inc Attn: Amazon.com' >
document 2
</#if>
```

Thank you,
Erica

Answer (score 2):

You can extract `PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME` into a variable, like `<#assign retName = PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME>`, and then it's somewhat shorter (`<#if retName == 'foo' || retName == 'bar'>`, etc.). Also, if you have a lot of strings to compare with, `<#if ['foo', 'bar', 'baaz']?seq_contains(retName)>` might be nicer.

Comment: ddekany,
Thank you SO MUCH!!! That is what I was looking for. I was having a hard time figuring out how to do this via the documents online. Was getting the assign backwards...putting the variables in there instead of the data location.
I ended up using your second IF <#if ['foo', 'bar', 'baaz']?seq_contains(retName)>.

Thanks again,
Erica

Answer (score 1):

Follow Freemrker [Comparison](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/dgui_template_exp.html#dgui_template_exp_comparison) example and use `==` and `"`:

```
<#if PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME == "BEST BUY" || PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME == "Best Buy Purchasing LLC">
document 1 
<#elseif  PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME == "AMAZON" || PRINTER_PET.RETAILER_NAME == "Amazon Fulfillment Services Inc Attn: Amazon.com" >
document 2
</#if>
```

> The `user == "Big Joe"` expression in the `<#if ...>` will evaluate to the boolean `true`, so the above will say "It is Big Joe".
>
> Logical or: ||